# Generate lists with elements less or equal to the given list

Tags: python, list

What is the most pythonic way to solve the following problem?

Given a list A, find all lists B, such that for i in range(len(A)): B[i] <= A[i]. Example of what I expect:

```
#Input
A = [1,2,0]
#Output
B = [[0,0,0],
     [1,0,0],
     [1,1,0],
     [1,2,0],
     [0,1,0],
     [0,2,0]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` to do this easily

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> A
[1, 2, 0]
>>> B = list(product(*[list(range(e+1)) for e in A]))
>>> B
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 2, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (1, 2, 0)]
>>>
```

If you want the o/p as list of list, convert the tuples to list

```
>>> B = [list(e) for e in B]
>>> B
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 0]]
>>>
```

If you dont wan't to use `itertools.product`, you can have your custom implementation of `product`

```
>>> B = [[]]; 
>>> for t in [range(e+1) for e in A]:
...     B = [x+[y] for x in B for y in t]
... 
>>> B
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 0]]
>>>
```

Comment: Great! The itertools was in my list. Unfortunatelly, I'm not allowed to use any side libraries. Maybe there are straightforward solutions without it? Thanks!

Comment: I can't see it working for an arbitrary len(A). Am I missing something? Is is possible to extend your second solution to any len(A)?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: @Sanitha, looks awesome! Maybe you know, why does the itertools implementation work much faster than the custom implementation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quite smart solution without using `itertools` but using recursive function call. It works whatever the size of the input list:

```
A = [1,2,0]

def compute(A, B=[], n=0):
    for i in range(A[n]+1):
        A[n] = i
        if A not in B: B.append(A[:])
        if n+1 < len(A): compute(A, B, n+1)  # recursive call here
    return sorted(B)

B = compute(A)

print(B)
# [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could first generate all unique combinations of these numbers:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> A = [1,2,0]
>>> combs = set(itertools.combinations(itertools.chain(*(range(col+1) for col in A)), len(A)))
>>> combs
{(0, 1, 1), (0, 2, 0), (1, 1, 0), (1, 2, 0), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 2), (0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 2)}
```

Then pick the ones that follow your condition:

```
>>> sorted(comb for comb in combs if all(comb[i] <= x for i, x in enumerate(A)))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 2, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (1, 2, 0)]
```

But this is alot more inefficient than using `itertools.product`, since it has to generate all the combinations beforehand, and sort at the end to retain order.

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
A = [1,2,0]

answers = [[] for element in A]
answers[0] = [[number,] for number in range(A[0]+1)]

for i in range(len(A)-1):
    for possibility in answers[i]:
        for valid_number in range(A[i+1]+1):
            answers[i+1].append(possibility + [valid_number, ])

your_answer = answers[-1]
```

It could probably be written in a more compact way.